# Showing that a set is a continuity set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, probability-theory, continuity

Consider a real-valued random variable $X$ defined on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{B}, P)$.

Consider $B:=(-\infty,x] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ with $P(X\leq x)$ continuous at $x$.

Let $\delta B:=\bar{B}-B^{\circ}$ be the boundary of $B$ where $\bar{B}$ is the closure and $B^{\circ}$ is the interior of $B$.

Show that $P(X \in \delta B)=0$.

Any suggestion? In particular, I do not understand what is the boundary of $B$.

Comment: This need not be true

Comment: @Amr I have edited the question, I hope it makes sense now. It is from "asymptotic statistics" of van der Vaart, p. 7

Comment: $\delta B = \{x\}$ in the usual topology on the reals...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use standard notation $\partial$ for boundary. Since $B$ is close set, $\bar{B}=B$ and $B^o=(-\infty, x)$. So $\partial B=\bar{B}-B^o=\{x\}$. Since $P(X\leqslant x)$ is continuous at $x$, 
$$
\lim_{\Delta x\to0}P(X\leqslant x+\Delta x)=P(X\leqslant x)
$$
And thus
\begin{align}
P(X \in \partial B)&=\lim_{\Delta x\to0}P(x<X\leqslant x+\Delta x)
\\
&=\lim_{\Delta x\to0}(P(X\leqslant x+\Delta x)-P(X\leqslant  x))
\\
&=\lim_{\Delta x\to0}P(X\leqslant x+\Delta x)-P(X\leqslant x)
\\
&=0
\end{align}